# How to stop VS Code interactive python (Jupyter) extension from starting the ipykernel on random ports in remote docker?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am developing remotely through the Remote-SSH + Remote-Containers plugins in VS Code, in other words I am ssh-ing into a remote server that runs a container with my configuration. Sometimes I need to do some quick visualisation or testing, so I like to use jupyter notebooks.

When I created the container I exposed only the 8888 port. If I start a notebook from command line, everything works fine, the jupyter server gets automatically launched at my container's 127.0.0.1:8888 and I can open it in the browser on my local machine. However, when I want to open the Jupyter interactive session using the Jupyter VS Code extension I can't do it, the interactive window opens and hangs saying it's

> Waiting for the Jupyter session to be idle

I can see however, that whenever I try to open the interactive Jupyter window, it doesn't automatically start at the 8888 port, but on random different ports. I assumed that is the problem. Is my diagnosis correct? The question then would be: how to force the Jupyter VS code extension to use 8888 port for the interactive window?

[Print screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mPTU.png)

Comment: The VS Code extension doesn't actually configure the port. That should be jupyter in the background doing that. Is it possible that you have something configuring ports on that box? Like changing the NotebookApp.port in the global Jupyter config file https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html. Also this could be a configuration of the SSH extension, do you have some type of port forwarding configured? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_forwarding-a-port-creating-ssh-tunnel